# Using Firebase Emulators and the @firebase/testing library, how can you update a user's custom claims?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a cloud function that changes a user's custom claim when a certain field changes.

I'm writing unit test for my app using firebase emulators. I need to manually change the user claim (since functions won't run in testing mode). I want to test that the database denies access to a user after his custom claims have been changed by the cloud function

thank you

Comment: `@firebase/testing` is deprecated please use `@firebase/rules-unit-testing`. The docs for it [are here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests#rut-v2-common-methods).

Comment: I'm using the firebase sdk version 8

Comment: The documentation I linked also has the steps you would use for v8 further down.

Comment: The steps for v8 uses "initializeTestApp", which is a function from `@firebase/testing`.

Answer (score 0):

`@firebase/testing` is deprecated and was last updated Oct 2020.

Use `@firebase/rules-unit-testing` instead:

- For v8.10.0 of the Web SDK, use `npm install @firebase/rules-unit-testing@1.3.15` (from Aug 2021, the last update before Firebase v9).
- For v9.0.0 onwards, in both modular and namespaced modes, use `npm install @firebase/rules-unit-testing`.

Technically they used to be the same package, but one is getting new updates whereas the other isn't. Because they were built from the same code base, their APIs are similar when dealing with the legacy namespaced Firebase SDK. For all new code, you should use `@firebase/rules-unit-testing` alongside the modular SDK and [modular test methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests#run_local_unit_tests_with_the_version_9_javascript_sdk).

Based on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests#rut-v1-testing):

```
import * as firebase from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing"; // note this "firebase" is not the normal firebase namespace!

const testApp = firebase.initializeTestApp({
  projectId: "my-test-project",
  auth: {
    uid: "alice",
    email: "alice@example.com",
    isAdmin: true,               // custom claim
    isModerator: true            // custom claim
  }
});
```

If using the normal Firebase namespace in your code, import the test library with this instead:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase"; // for v8 or older.
import * as firebaseTest from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";
```